# Unable to Set Selected Value Of DropDown In angularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a DropDown. I'm binding it's value using `ng-repeat` on Option. 
I want to Set the selected value using the value field only .

This is My code.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectedItemvalue">
        <option value="">--Select --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="sel in selectables" value="{{sel.value}}">{{sel.label}}</option>
    </select>
    <p>Selected Value is : {{selectedItemvalue}}</p>
</div>
```

Js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

// controller here
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectables = [
        { label: 'A', value: 1},
        { label:'B', value: 2},
        { label: 'C', value: 3}
    ];

    // this is the model that's used for the data binding in the select directive
    // the default selected item
    //using value, i want to set the selected value
    $scope.selectedItemvalue = "2"; 
})
```

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TU6tp/26/)

As you can see, I want to set selected value uisng only By setting Value.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use `ng-model` instead of `ng-value` to bind it to model.

```
<select ng-model="selectedItemvalue">
```

**Update:**   `$scope.selectedItem` needs to be `$scope.selectedItemvalue` in controller and then you can use `ng-selected` to match condition on it

**Working Demo**

```js
angular
.module('myApp', [])

// controller here
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.selectables = [
        { label: 'A', value: 1},
        { label:'B', value: 2},
        { label: 'C', value: 3}
    ];

    // this is the model that's used for the data binding in the select directive
    // the default selected item
    //using value, i want to set the selected value
    $scope.selectedItemvalue = "2"; 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
    <select ng-model="selectedItemvalue">
        <option value="">--Select --</option>
        <option ng-repeat="sel in selectables" ng-selected="selectedItemvalue == sel.value" value="{{sel.value}}">{{sel.label}}</option>
    </select>
 <p>Selected Value is : {{selectedItemvalue}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: See the Updated Link. Still Same problem

Comment: But Intially , second Itme Is not Selected in your Demo,

Comment: you want second item to be selected inititially?

Comment: @AmitKumar see the answer and demo now

Comment: @AB: yes. It can be any item. Like If I set `$scope.selectedItemvalue = "3"; ` then It will Set Selected Item Whose Value filed Is 3

Comment: @AmitKumar i hope now it is done accordingly see demo

Comment: It's Working. But see this in firefox. It is adding an extra Blank option .I have used your code .
http://jsfiddle.net/TU6tp/27/

Comment: i am using firefox too, but it is --select-- option only nothing else extra @AmitKumar

Comment: can you explain me the concept of ng-selected having model == array.value and you also have to give model a value from controller so what is really happening ...if both the value matches it gets selected like that ?

Answer (score 7):

You need to basically use the following syntax for your `option` tag (use `ng-selected`):

```
<option ng-repeat="sel in selectables" value="{{sel.value}}" ng-selected="sel.value == selectedItemvalue">{{sel.label}}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try

$scope.selectedItemvalue = { label:'B', value: 2};

then it will work.

Comment: Hii. No I want to creat object to set Selected Value. I just Want to set using Value field.

Comment: then try as  <option ng-repeat="sel.value for sel in selectables"