# How to change the value of the text or select a dropdown value by using document.getElementById("id")

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to select the option with the value we give using document.getElementById("id"):

```
document.getElementById("dropdownlist").selectedValue="apple";
```

or change the text of a control with the help of this in javascript code.

i am filling the dropdown like this:

```
 <select id="ddlC" class="form-control" ng-model="mdlC" runat="server" style="width: 250px" ng-options="c.CId as c.Na for c in Cat">
                <option value="">Select Category</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value="apple";

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499405/change-the-selected-value-of-a-drop-down-list-with-jquery

Comment: check this. It will surely help you with this. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047923/working-with-select-using-angularjss-ng-options

Comment: Have done exactly the same way

Comment: [Here is how you have to prepare the select and with ng-selected you can give value to its model and bang ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28169691/12141266)

Comment: kudos kudos kudos  kudos 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change **selectedValue** to **value**

```
document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value = "apple";
```

Comment: it did not got selected

Comment: do you have value attribute in options?
`<option value='apple'>Apple</option>`
And do you have the id `dropdownlist ` unique in your DOM?

Comment: yes i do have that

Comment: wait i think i dont have that sorry let me check and thank you so much

Comment: Let me know. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var element = document.getElementById("dropdownlist");
    element.value = "apple";
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140862/how-to-select-a-value-in-dropdown-javascript)

Through `document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value = "option3";` you can set a specific option to be selected

```js
var dropDownOptions = ["option1", "option2", "option3", "others"]
 var options = "";
 
for (option in dropDownOptions) {
    options += "<option>" + dropDownOptions[option] + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("dropdownlist").innerHTML = options;

// select option by value
document.getElementById("dropdownlist").value = "option3";
```

```html
<select name="category" id="dropdownlist"/>
```